# Couples should couples refrain from sex on first day of New Years

Tags: buddha

My fiancé in VN tells me couples must refrain from sex on first day of new year. I have not found anything supporting this claim. Where do I find more information about no sex on day one new year.

Comment: I guessed it might be related to observing the 8 precepts on Uposatha days -- but that's the full moon, whereas the Lunar New Year starts on the first new moon of the calendar.

Comment: @ChrisW According to the Wikipedia page on Uposatha, both full moon and new moon days are Uposatha days in most Theravada countries. So the 8 precepts hypothesis makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Chinese new year falls on New-moon Uposatha, so good, if not always, observing it. Nothing wrong, but the opposite, to follow the whole life without "Dhamma of the villagers".